# selecting rows that are the same in one column, but different in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
X    Y    DATE
1    20   20120101
1    21   20120101
2    30   20120201
3    40   20120201
3    41   20120301
```

I want to select any rows that have another row where X is the same, but the date is different, i.e. the answer would be

```
3    40   20120201
3    41   20120301
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) Mar 29 2009 10:11:52 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) .... why?

Comment: Because my sql will only work from sqlserver 2008+.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE X IN (
  SELECT T1.X
  FROM YourTable T1 INNER JOIN
       YourTable T2 ON T1.X = T2.X
  WHERE T1.DATE <> T2.DATE
);
```

This should work in most ANSI-compliant database products.

Comment: this is a working answer, by my vendor's sql implementation doesn't allow nested selects - but i appreciate the help

Comment: i actually think i'm still a little confused, can you give the answer for just the x and y columns above to the question, 'which have the same Y and differing X'?

Comment: @gmaximus: You tagged your question with sql-server-2008, and you said you were using SQL Server 2008. So what do you mean when you say your vendor's sql implementation doesn't allow nested selects? SQL Server 2008 definitely allows nested selects.

Comment: The company that my company bought software from only included implementations for one select command at a time - I don't have access to a proper server unless I do some workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct t1.*
  from table t1
  join table t2
    on (t1.X = t2.X and t1.date <> t2.date);
```

Comment: @Yuck I don't have an opportunity to test it, but are your sure? It seems to me that this query should give the result needed.

Comment: `table` is a SQL keyword, which would prevent this from running. What did you actually run to test? And which RDBMS?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov you are wrong, this will not work In all situations. Imagine 3 different dates for the same X.

Comment: @Yuck table is a placeholder for the real table name.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk The only thing that was missing - `distinct` =) I've tested in on MySQL and it works well. If there are 3 different dates for the same X then we'll have each of these dates repeated 2 times and `distinct` removes duplicates. You can try it for yourself.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov yes, you can fix the result with a distinct. but you are still getting a slow as hell query in a table with alot of identical X'is because you are joining on all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(X int, Y int, DATE CHAR(8))
insert @t values
(1, 20, '20120101' ),
(1, 21, '20120101' ),
(2, 30, '20120201'),
(3, 40, '20120201'),
(3, 41, '20120301')

select x,y, date, maxy, miny from
(
  select *, max(date) over (partition by x) maxdate, 
  min(date) over (partition by x) mindate
  from @t
) a
where mindate <> maxdate
```